# Get n-th element from all dictionary values - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there any out of the box syntax/func that would return n-th value of all dictionary keys. For example `n=2` for the following dic

```
dic = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4],
       'b': [5, 6, 7, 8],
       'c': [9, 10, 11, 12]}
```

would return:

```
newdic = {'a': 3,
          'b': 7,
          'c': 11}
```

For now I defined the following function which works fine, but I find it kind of ugly.

```
def nth_value(n, **kwargs):
    dic = {}
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        dic[key] = value[n]
    return dic
```

P.S. I know for sure that all lists are of same length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> n = 2 
>>> {k:v[n] for k,v in dic.items()}
{'c': 11, 'b': 7, 'a': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Improvement to avoid `IndexError: list index out of range`:

```
>>> dic = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4],
           'b': [5, 6, 7, 8],
           'c': [9, 10, 11, 12]}

>>> n = 3
>>> {k:v[n] if n < len(v) else None for k, v in dic.items()}
{'a': 4, 'b': 8, 'c': 12}

>>> del dic['b'][-1]
>>> {k:v[n] if n < len(v) else None for k, v in dic.items()}
{'a': 4, 'b': None, 'c': 12}
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwer but it was not necessary, since as I said I know that all lists are of same length. However, it might be useful to someone else. :)

Comment: @narn hopefully yes, anyway even if you know that the list are of same length it doesnt mean you are immune to `IndexError` if you choose a `n` too big.

Comment: That is true. However this was just an example, in my case I get value of n from for loop in range of length of list. So I should be safe.